# Значение (функция) союза "чтобы" в предложениях типа "Не+глагол, чтобы...."

Tags: союзы

В роли какого союза выступает союз "чтобы" в предложениях типа:

1.Не было и дня, чтобы Федор не курил.
2.Не вижу, чтобы волк выходил из лесу.

Мне кажется, что и в роли изъяснительного и определительного, но почему именно "чтобы"? Какую-то роль здесь играет частица "не", т.к именно с ней применяется союз "чтобы".

Comment: Обычный подчинительный союз.

Comment: Мне кажется здесь роль союза "чтобы" двойственна - и определительная и изъяснительная.

Comment: Получается, изъяснительный. При целевом вопрос "зачем?". Виды здесь: https://russkiiyazyk.ru/sintaksis/podchinitelnye-soiuzy.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Не было и дня, чтобы Федор не курил***. Интересное для анализа предложение и довольно сложное.

1. Его семантика имеет **как определительное, так и изъяснительное** значение, поэтому его следует отнести к моделям **фразеологического** характера. Впрочем, эта модель используется в литературе, поэтому считать ее неправильной нежелательно:

*За последние недели не было **и дня, чтобы** я не фотографировал, и мои карточки уже хвалили на студии.*
Александр Снегирев. Как же ее звали?.. // «Знамя», 2013

*С той минуты **не было и дня, чтобы** он не пожалел о своей комнате в коммуне, о которой прежде вспоминал только от скандала к скандалу.*
Сергей Шикера. Маклер // «Волга», 2012

2. По грамматике э**то определительное придаточное**, так что  союз ЧТОБЫ определительный.  Сравнить: *Не было и дня,  в течение **которого** Федор не курил бы.*

Союз ЧТОБЫ обозначает **ирреальное действие** (которое происходит обычно, но не конкретное/реальное). Вообще этот союз **нехарактерен** для определительных придаточных и связан **с отрицанием**.

Сравнить: *День, ЧТО (который)  прошел, запомнился ему* (**обычное** определительное придаточное).

3. Отнести предложение **к изъяснительным придаточным нельзя,** так как опорное существительное **не ментальное**. Сравнить: *Не было и МЫСЛИ, чтобы уехать* (изъяснительное придаточное при наличии отрицания и ирреальной модальности).

Предложения с нементальными опорными словами называются **вмещающими изъяснительными**, но они требуют обязательного присутствия **указательного** слова. Но это уже  **переходный тип** придаточных (фактически местоименно-определительное с изъяснительным значением).

***Не вижу, чтобы волк выходил из лесу***. Обычное **изъяснительное** придаточным с изъяснительным ирреальным союзом ЧТОБЫ при отрицании действия: не вижу. Реальное действие не совершается. Сравнить: **Я вижу что/как волк выходит из леса** (без отрицания, обычные изъяснительные союзы).

Comment: Такой развернутый комментарий! Блестяще! Спасибо.

Comment: Спасибо и вам!!  За оценку и интересный вопрос.

Answer (score 3):

В первом случае союз "чтобы" присоединяет определительное придаточное предложение.

**Не было и дня(какого?), чтобы Федор не курил**.

Второе предложение - придаточное изъяснительное.

**Не вижу(чего?),чтобы волк выходил из лесу.**

Следует отметить, что не все учебники упоминают союз "чтобы" в придаточном определительном, т.к. в этом типе предложения союз используется редко и придает предложению разговорный оттенок. В этом случае союз "чтобы" имеет оттенок изъяснительного или целевого значения.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!